# How to assign a colour to a variable in Fore (colorama)

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a function that gets an inputted string and returns it with a random colour. (The random colour is defined earlier)

```
print(Fore.randomColour + inputVariable)
```

Whenever I try something along those lines, I end up with the error:
AttributeError: 'AnsiFore' object has no attribute 'randomColour'
I have tried using getattr, but I still couldn't get it to work. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list with your defined colors and then pick it randomly.

```py
import random
bcolors = ['\033[95m','\033[94m','\033[92m','\033[93m','\033[91m','\033[1m']
print (random.choice(bcolors) + "random color" + '\033[0m')
```

where '\033[0m' means reset